# Wrap items in a windows applications List View control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview

Is there a way to make long items wrap in a .net windows forms application,  I have already got LabelWrap set to true, but it doesn't work, I am using Details View Type,

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ListView doesn't allow text-wrapping.

What I usually do is set "ShowItemToolTips" property true in such cases. Then user can see the whole text a ToolTip. This is the only simple option I can see with ListView to help in this case.

If you really want to support for text-wrapping you will have to either use a third party ListView or use a DataGridView.

**EDIT**
If you are using VS2010, [Tile View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z85th0.aspx) is an option for you.

> With the tile view feature of the ListView control, you can provide a
>   visual balance between graphical and textual information. The textual
>   information displayed for an item in tile view is the same as the
>   column information defined for details view. Tile view works in
>   combination with either the grouping or insertion mark features in the
>   ListView control.

Comment: I think i will go with the grid view control, too bad List View doesn;t allow text-wrapping, is this even documented in msdn? and what is the LabelWrap  for?

Comment: @HassanMokdad , But how to use the LabelWrap ?

Answer (score 4):

The LabelWrap property only works for icons (View types of LargeIcon or SmallIcon), not Details.  As others have already answered, you have to use DataGridView or a 3rd party listview such as [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).